# Merging content of tsv's from a folder into a dataframe

Tags: pandas, loops, csv, directory, append

I am trying to merge tsv files from a local folder into a pandas dataframe.
I am trying to iterate over the folders and to append them to a the dataframe.
This is what i tried so far:

```
bigdf=[]
for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\xxxx'):
    print(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\' + file, sep='\t')
    bigdf.append(df)
```

'file' only gives me the filename and not the content of the file itsself.
the 4th line does not work entirely. Does anyone know how to loop over the files in a way that the content gets appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct but you can try something like that:

```
import pathlib

rootdir = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\xxxx')

data = []
for file in rootdir.glob('*.tsv'):
    print(file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t')
    data.append(df)

bigdf = pd.concat(data)  # or pd.concat(data, axis='columns')
```